# Question about free function and memory allocation ( C )

Tags: c, pointers, memory, free

I'm trying to understand and pointers and memory allocation in C. So I have these lines of C code:

```
int *a=0; // a pointer which points to 0
a = (int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));  // now the pointers a points to the adress of our allocated memory, right ?
if (a == 0) 
{
   fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("The value of a is %p\n", a); // this is the adress of our allocated memory
a=readArray(5); // a function which reads and array // What happens here? I read an array in that memory which I allocated, right ?
printf("Now the value of a is: %p\n", a); // Now the adress is the adress of first array element, right?
if (a != 0)
{
   free(a);
   a=0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
The value of a is 0x7ff780c03160
Now the value of a is: 0x7ff780c03180
```

Now I need pick an answer about the call of free function.

```
1. Deallocates the both allocated memory zones.
2. Deallocates the memory starting at adress 0x7ff780c03180 and fill that zone with zeros.
3. Deallocates the memory starting at adress 0x7ff780c03180
4. Deallocates the memory starting at adress 0x7ff780c03160
```

From what I read about free function, it deallocates the whole memory and it's recommended to initialize the pointer with 0. So I think the answer is the first variant, 1. Am I right ?

Comment: What does `readArray` do?

Comment: Is a function which I use to read some numbers from keyboard.

Comment: Where did you get those answers? What is "both memory zones?" Neither answer is correct unless you allocate new memory in that function. Otherwise `free` will report an error.

Comment: you allocate new memory in that function? this seems to be a memory leak...

Comment: The answers are not in English, I translated so this may be the reasons it sounds wrong

Comment: free deallocates the zone you told it to free. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, `free` won't deallocate more than the allocated pointer passed to it. The correct answer from your list is 3. `free` will deallocate the memory pointed by `a` at that point in time and that's it. It won't fill that memory zone with zero or anything else.

Also, when you `readArray(5)`, you create allocate new memory and leave aside the old allocated one before. So what you are doing step-by-step:

1. Allocated some memory (let's call it `X`) using `malloc` and store its address in variable `a`.
2. Call `readArray` which will allocate some other memory (let's call it `Y`) and store its address in `a`.
3. Free the memory which is stored in `a`, which is the `Y` allocated memory chunk.

Now the memory labeled `X` will be dangling, meaning that you don't have any reference to it and you have no ways of deallocating it. It's just allocated memory which cannot be reached anymore, as you lost the pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

`readArray` has no access to `a` (`a` isn't a global variable, nor is it passed to `readArray`), meaning that `readArray` must allocate a new array and return it. This array is then assigned to `a`, losing the reference to the original `malloc`ed array in the process.

The `free` call is applied to the new array starting at `0x7ff780c03180`, making the correct answer #3.

Answer (score 2):

No, `free()` will deallocate only the memory block given by the pointer passed to it. So this will deallocate the memory starting at the address 0x7ff780c03180, and the memory at address 0x7ff780c03160 will be leaked.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `3`.

With the line `a=readArray(5);` you are losing the previous pointer (160 in your example). You cannot `free` this memory anymore, so you have a memory leak. ==> `1` and `4` cannot be the correct answer.

`free` does not fill the memory with zeros, also `a=0` sets only the pointer variable to `0`, but does nothing with the memory ==> `2` is not the correct answer.